# Horizontal Scroll View(Image View)

Tags: android, android-studio, horizontalscrollview

I have a Horizonal scroll view with Images. Then the output is this.
I loaded 2 same pictures but the Gap is too much.
I just want it to make like 5Margins on left but didn't get the result.
Here's my Code.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="#FFF"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/imgLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                    </LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And here is my code of Adding imageviews to linear layout.

```
public void setImageViews() {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imgLayout);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            parms.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
            for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
                ImageView  imageView =new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bsu);
                linearLayout.addView(imageView);

    }
}
```

The results i got.
I want it to be 5margins apart.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the result when you set no margins or even no LayoutParams at all?

Comment: same result i got when i removed the layout params

Comment: can you provide the link for the image in order to have your issue tested?

Comment: i have tested the same code you provide using a 72x72 image and it works as it is expected..

Comment: as it's expected? so you got the same result or the way i want?